# how to make wavy line animation inside svg circle

Tags: animation, svg

I have a loader gif, but I want this animation using svg
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3oJC.gif

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy:

```html
<svg>
  <rect fill="blue" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="140"/>
  <circle fill="white" cx="150" cy="70" r="60" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />
  <path fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" d="M0,0 Q 30,-30 60,0 Q 90,30 120,0 Q 150,-30 180,0 210,30 240,0">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="translate"
                          from="-30 70"
                          to="90 70"
                          dur="1s"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: wow amazing !! Thanks a lot for your help ;)