# svg infinite wave animation

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make my SVG wave infinite but I'm running across the issue where the endpoints wont meet. As in the wave continues forever but you can clearly see the cut-off for the svg.

***HTML**

```
     <div class="nav-image">
        <h1 class="navdescriptionfirst animate__animated animate__fadeInDown ">Post</h1>
        <h1 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown animate__delay-1s">Find</h1>
        <h1 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown animate__delay-2s">Trade</h1>
        <img id="wave" src="wave.svg">
    </div
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-image {
  background-color: var(--color-one);
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 
}

.nav-image img {
  width: 200%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: wave linear 20s infinite;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
}
```

[link to repl with full code](https://replit.com/@MagaBeyworld/LastYellowgreenPagerecognition#index.html)

I've made the animation speed faster so that you can see what I mean when the endpoints won't meet.

What should I change for them to meet or look infinite?

Comment: I hope it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776909/how-to-make-wavy-line-animation-inside-svg-circle/66780404#66780404

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make wavy line animation inside svg circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776909/how-to-make-wavy-line-animation-inside-svg-circle)